# Does Java optimize away a field that's just serving as a return value?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

**Why I'm asking:**

I wanted to know it there is any optimization going on at the compiler side that would make one or the other method to return preferable. Since I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390869/does-python-optimize-away-a-variable-thats-only-used-as-a-return-value) that python does not optimize the method to run faster.

**The example:**

I've declared 2 methods that deliver the same value. But `barA` returns it via an internal field declaration.

```
public class Foo {
    public int barA(){
        int a = 1;
        return a;
    }

    public int barB(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**The tests:**

```
public class TestFoo {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Method methodA = foo.getClass().getMethod("barA");
    Method methodB = foo.getClass().getMethod("barB");


    public TestFoo() throws NoSuchMethodException {
    }


    @Test
    public void methodA() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(Integer.TYPE.equals(methodA.getReturnType()));
    }

    @Test
    public void methodB() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(Integer.TYPE.equals(methodB.getReturnType()));
    }
    @Test
    public void equalsSame() throws Exception{
        assertEquals(foo.barA(), foo.barB());
    }
}
```

**The results:**

The tests showed that I'm in fact dealing with the same value and return type in both methods.

**Disclaimer:**
This picture is not meant to highlight the stop watch, junit runs for each method, as it's in no way linked to the compiler optimization I'm asking about.

[image: The tests]

**The question:**

Does Java actually try to optimize away "useless" field declarations in order to execute faster?

I was not able to find a question addressing this.

**Using:**

- jdk 1.8.0_121
- junit 4.10

Comment: That's not a field, that's a local variable. "Java" has no requirement to try and optimize these things, so if I made a Java compiler that doesn't optimize this and conforms to everything Java requires, it would be a valid Java compiler. But I guarantee that the common distributions of Java you'll find, do remove the useless local variable.

Comment: I really doubt that your test have anything to say. Probably even your execution times are below 1ms because those methods are not computating anything

Comment: Check the generated byte code if there is a difference. Also the JIT compiler could make some additional optimizations. But if I was you, I would not care too much about these micro optimizations.

Comment: @Michael It all starts with "false" assumptions ... and I am looking to add more relevant information here.

Comment: The compiler isn't required to analyze the flow enough to find out that they are the same. But in practice, it does find out.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. Lets see how long it will stick ;-)

Comment: And for the record: I updated the first paragraph a bit to be more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the updates by the OP, the real answer here is very basic: java is a statically compiled language.

The signature of a method ... is what the signature says. The signature says to return a int value. And that is what any method with int on its signature will return. Nothing in the Java architecture allows you to dynamically change such things at runtime. From that point of view, your tests for the return type are all bogus. The language design implies that the answer is always "the method returns `int`. And please note: if the return type would be a reference type, say `Number`, then of course you could have one method return an instance of Long, and another one an Integer object (resulting in different types, but still subtypes of Number)!

Beyond that, the OP talks about *looking at the different execution times*.

Yes, junit runs a stop watch to roughly tell you how long each test runs. But that is **not** measuring. In order to understand the true performance impacts of code, you have to do real measurement. From that point of view: the numbers from JUnit don't mean what you think they mean. They are not a suitable base to draw such conclusions from.

See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) for further guidance on how one *could* get to more meaningful numbers.

Comment: Could you add an example what a "real" measurement with this example would look like and how to do it, for the sake of completeness?

Answer (score 3):

If we take the example:

```
class Main  {
    int foo() {
        int i = 0;
        return i;
    }

    int bar() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().foo();
        new Main().bar();
    }
}
```

And view the bytecode:

```
class my.pckage.Main extends java.lang.Object{
my.pckage.Main();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

int foo();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0  //push zero onto the stack
   1:   istore_1  //pop off the stack and store in local variable
   2:   iload_1   //load an int value from local variable 1
   3:   ireturn   //return an integer from a method

int bar();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   ireturn

public static void main(java.lang.String[])   throws java.lang.Exception;
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class my/pckage/Main
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method "<init>":()V
   7:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method foo:()I
   10:  pop
   11:  new     #2; //class my/pckage/Main
   14:  dup
   15:  invokespecial   #3; //Method "<init>":()V
   18:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method bar:()I
   21:  pop
   22:  return

}
```

You can see that it's not being optimised away at this level.

As to whether the JIT compiler decides to optimise this at runtime will depend on the specific platform being targeted.