# Optimize away useless assignements and dict/members access in python functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, compilation, jit

I hear that python functions are compiled to bytecode as soon as they are defined.

But, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43390869/3719101), only very few optimizations are made during this step.

So, when I define this python function:

```
def dummy(obj):
    i = obj
    a = i
    o = a
    return o
```

is it *not* optimized to  / interpreted as / equivalent to:

```
def dummy(obj):
    return obj
```

by the interpreter/compiler.

As for objects member/dict access, this function:

```
def dummy(obj):
    res = obj.member + obj.member ** 2
    return [res, obj.member]
```

is *not* optimized to:

```
def dummy(obj):
    mb = obj.member
    return [mb + mb ** 2, mb]
```

Since python does not perform this simple job, which seems automatable yet non-trivial, are there tools to do this?

Comment: @Kasramvd I've moved the focus towards alternative tools, which are not adressed in the duplicate. Is it enough for the question to be reopened?

Comment: It's mentioned in that answer that this behavior is specifically attributed to a particular implementation. Therefore, if you look for such tools you may be able to find it in other implementations such as PyPy, Jython, etc.

Comment: @Kasramvd Okay, thanks :) Do I close this post then?

Comment: It's already closed you can delete it if you want tho.